# How to open a webbrowser inside a WP7 application , using a specific URL?

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser

I am developing an application , that i only need to do 2 things :

1) *Use push notifications.*

2) *Open a **specific URL** on startup.*

I wrote the push notification code inside my only mainpage and looks like this :

```
namespace WindowsPush
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            /// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
            HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

            // The name of our push channel.
            string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

            InitializeComponent();

            // Try to find the push channel.
            pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

            // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
            if (pushChannel == null)
            {
                pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

                // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                //pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                pushChannel.Open();

                // Bind this new channel for toast events.
                pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

            }
            else
            {
                // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                //pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
                // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

            }


        }


        void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                // Display the new URI for testing purposes.   Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", e.ChannelUri.ToString()));
            });
        }


        void PushChannel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}", e.ErrorType, e.Message, e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorAdditionalData)));
        }


    }
}
```

This code is inside MainPage.xaml.cs .  How do i open in here a specific URL ?

Comment: Use WebBrowserTask to open specific URL in built in browser.

Comment: But Toni in top down it shows me the URL and i can manually type any URL that i want. I just need to open a URL and nothing like this. I dont want the user to be able to leave the URL by typing manually another URL.

Comment: You will need to clarify that for me. Do you want to navigate in-app or open browser?

Comment: in-app. But i dont want the user to be able to change the url or anything. I want just one view in my app that is an external url. nothing else.Then the user will be able to navigate to other urls only through the url i ve provided him. That means he can only navigate to my project and nowhere else

Comment: Why don't you show him that URL in a HyperlinkButton control?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. I am not a c# developer. I just need to open a specific URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) in Windows Phone, there are two approaches.

Use [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Use [WebBrowser Control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Mini-browser-Sample-b5587d2b)

You can take either of the above approaches to display the contents of a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator), as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use WebBrowserTask. How can i add in the end of the URL the deviceID so that i open the url www.example.com/thisIsMyDeviceId

Comment: But wait. I just implemented it. In top down it shows me the URL and i can manually type any URL that i want. I just need to open a URL and nothing like this. I dont want the user to be able to leave the URL by typing manually another URL.

Comment: And where do i place the code? Cause i tried to place it in the public MainPage before the last } , but the push notification was not working. Actually the code was not called i think , cause i couldnt see the URI getting printed in the console as it should. Also when i hit the back button i was in a blank page. I only want to see the URL and nothing else. I need the push working and not any blank page.